# JavaScript array from parsing JSON is undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, json, undefined

So, the gecko thing again, the [JSON](http://www.texaslizardconnection.com/components/lizards.json) that im using in this script to populate a listbox is valid according to JSONLint, and im usig code like this to place the parsed data in arrays

```
pdata = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
ctype = pdata[0];
stype = pdata[1];
lizlist = pdata[2];
```

now, it gets t one point where I loop through the array ctype (look at the JSON file I linked for reference) using this code

```
lbt = "";
for(var i in ctype) {
lbt += "<option value=\""+ctype[i].id"\"+>"+ctype[i].type+"</option>"
}
```

then it ake this code an place it in a listbox on the page. However, this listbox get populated with the value "undefined" and only one "undefined" (there should be three options, one header)
for the javascript file im talking about go [here](http://www.texaslizardconnection.com/components/js.js)
the page this is on is "http://texaslizardconnection.com/#newavailable" 
A little info about this javascript:

pdata[0]~pdata[2] should contain arrays 
pdata[2] should conatain more arrays 
pdata[0] == pdata["cType"] 
pdata[1] == pdata["sType"]
pdata[2] == pdata["lizlist"]

Answer (score 1):

replace your loop with:

```
for (var i=0;i< ctype.length; i++)
```

You're looping through every property of the ctype object.

Answer (score 0):

When you are looping over ctype, you forgot to specify to loop over the cType property.

This works:

```
for(var i in ctype.cType) {
    lbt += "<option value=\""+ctype.cType[i].id+"\">"+ctype.cType[i].type+"</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pdata = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
if (!pdata.cType) {
  alert('fail, cType is null');
} else if (!pdata.sType) {
  alert('fail, sType is null');
} else {
  // cType is an array!
  lbt = "";
  for (var i=0, item; item = pdata.cType[i]; i++) {
    lbt += "<option value=\""+item.id+"\">"+item.type+"</option>";
  }
  // and so on
}
```